# Reading emails with Python

Tags: email, imap

I am writing a python script which can read emails from a person's inbox.

```
import imaplib
import email

# Set up the IMAP connection
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('your_email_address', 'your_email_password')
mail.select('inbox')

# Search for all email messages in the inbox
status, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')

# Iterate through each email message and print its contents
for num in data[0].split():
    status, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    email_message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    print('From:', email_message['From'])
    print('Subject:', email_message['Subject'])
    print('Date:', email_message['Date'])
    print('Body:', email_message.get_payload())
    print()
    
# Close the connection
mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'
```

Even though my credentials are correct.

Some solutions online suggest to turn on Less Secure Apps on Google, however, this might not be suitable for everyone.

I know it is a little rough, but I am still learning, so any advice you have to help me improve would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Gmail is not a good server to learn with. To fully integrate with it you will need to use OAUTH2 and register your application with them.

Comment: I wanted to build a bot which can read emails and reply to it. Since Gmail is one of the popular services out there, I decided to choose it. What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an app password in your google account. I named mine 'Python' because I do not know if it works with a different name.
The option 'Less secure apps' no longer exists.